# Move specific files from specific folders

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch that will move all .ts files from subfolders to their parent folder, but only from folder that their name ends with "_ren".

This is how the folder looks like:
The main folder is in this path "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\general\".
In it I have multiple folders, some might contain subfolders and some might contain files (some folders are also empty).

I want to run a script that will move all .ts files (just ts) only from the folders (or subfolders) with "_ren" at the end of the folder name, and put those files in the parent folder "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\general\".

If the file already exist then it needs to be overwritten.
But that shouldn't happen, so if it's not possible then it's fine.

This is the script I have, but it's not doing anything with the files:

```
for /r %%i in ("\*_ren\*.ts") do move "%%i" "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\general\"
```

I trien different typos for the path like "%%_ren*.ts" or "_ren*.ts", with the full path, and without. Nothing worked.

I also tried:

```
for /r %%i in ("*.ts") do move "%%i" "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\general\"
```

It works fine, but it moves the ts files from all the folders, and not just those who end with "_ren".

I hope I explained it right.

Comment: Also, what happens if the filename being moved already exist in the destination directory? Show us the code you have created that failed to accomplish the task.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I made an edit to the request

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are using Windows. 
So, let using powershell to access library of .Net Framework.
Write a function read all files in folders -> Make a list of need-copy-file -> Run command to copy or move in this list to destination.